# Switch to this tab shortcut in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm looking for the shortcut to switch to this tab from Chrom address bar. Currently, I use the combo Tab + Enter, is there any combo key to complete this faster? 
Thanks

[image: Switch to this tab shortcut]

Comment: ctrl+tab....just like alt+tab for windows.

Comment: This is nice feature, does Chrome have a setting to show "Switch to this tab" listings in the top of the drop-down list? This would be great for navigating to another tab in other Chrome windows

Comment: Ah, so that's why it never worked for me! It's a damn button!!!! I thought it was just a "badge".

Answer (score 17):

**Update: Working Nov 2021 **

Press an **EXTRA  <kbd>TAB</kbd>**  to get to the "Switch to this tab" button.

Full sequence of keys:

- **(On Mac)** <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> - Get to address/search bar
- **(On PC)** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> - Get to address/search bar
- Start typing
- Use <kbd>↓</kbd> arrow to select the line with the correct "Switch to this tab" button
- Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to focus the button
- Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to select

<s>Unfortunately the method below stopped working for Mac.</s>

<s>If you're already using arrows to navigate through the url options - you can use `right arrow + enter`</s>

Comment: this doesn't work on Mac OS.

Comment: @ingenious I confirm, it stopped working on Mac & Windows. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Echoing the update: macOS confirmed working for me on macOS 10.14.6, Chrome 97.0.4692.71.

Answer (score 5):

To switch to a pre-existing tab from the list of suggestions.

<kbd>↓</kbd>  to select the correct suggestion + <kbd>tab</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

This will open the pre-existing tab for the webpage.

Comment: This is the same thing that the question says. He is seeking for a better way.

Comment: Tab+space works too and is easier to do.

Answer (score 4):

In new chrome versions (at least on mac os and at least since 90.0.4430.212) there is now a (not yet documented) shortcut you can use for this:

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>

this opens the search tabs dialogue where you can start typing and your query is matched against the list of currently open tabs. As Simon pointed out in the comments below, the shortcut on windows is

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>

However for whatever reason this shortcut is not yet documented in the chrome documentation at https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179

Comment: Sometimes this shortcut can be captured by the web-page, such as in Google Docs.